# JavaScript linter which detects reassignment?

Tags: javascript, lint

I'd like to know whether there exists a JavaScript linter which detects reassignment.

For example:

```
function foo(options) {
  options || (options = {});
  return bar(options);
}
// => Error: Reassignment to `options` on line 2

function product(nums) {
  p = 1;
  nums.forEach(function(nums) {
    p *= 1;
  });
  return p;
}
// => Error: Reassignment to `p` on line 4
```

Comment: I understand your first example (you don't want to change a formal parameter). But the second one? why would you never want to reassign a different value to a variable? That's very common (and often innocuous). If you want to prevent that, you can simply use `const` instead of `var`...

Comment: I now use `const`, but at the time I asked this question I was not targeting an environment which supported this language feature.

Comment: OK, so without `const`: wouldn't that rule throw lots of false positives? I mean, every time you assign a value to a variable. Is that something you actually avoid in your code, as a rule of coding style? I'm just curious and want to make sure I understand your question :)

Comment: Even before `const` was available I wrote code using single assignment. With a functional programming library such as [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/), reassignment is unnecessary.